# In Java if one thread got killed, what will happen to the other thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to know in Java:

1. If main  thread got killed what will happen to other children threads?
2. If child thread got killed what will happen to siblings and parent thread?

I read in the following link that since threads sharing  address space,  killing one thread can affect other thread also.

Below is a quote from [here](http://www.blurtit.com/q236205.html).

> Threads are light weight processes that divide main flow of control into multiple flows and each flow of control/thread will execute independently. Activity of the process in a system is represented by threads. The process that has multiple threads is called as multi threaded. Each threads has its own thread ID ( Data Type Integer), register, program counter, stack, error no. Threads can communicate using shared memory within same process.
>   There are different advantages of using threads to mange and maintain the subtask of applications. When we are using threads than less system resources are used for context switching and increased the throughput of application. Threads also simplify the structure of program. There is no special mechanism for communication between tasks.
>   Threads also have some disadvantages for example threads are not reusable as they are dependent on a process and cannot be separated from the process. Threads are not isolated as they don't have their own address space. The error cause by the thread can kill the entire process or program because that error affects the entire memory space of all threads use in that process or program. Due to the shared resources by the threads with in the process can also affect the whole process or program when a resource damage by the thread. For concurrent read and write access to the memory thread will required synchronizations. Data of the process can easily damage by the thread through data race because all the threads with in the process have write access to same piece of data.

Can u gys please tell whether whatever told in the above link is applicable to java

Answer (score 10):

1) Nothing will happen to the "child threads"...

2) Nothing will happen to the "sibling threads"...

...with the following exception: If all remaining threads are daemon threads, the application will terminate (i.e., when there are only daemon threads left, these will be killed as well).

From the [documentation of `Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> [...] The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of the following occurs:
>
> - The exit method of class Runtime has been called [...]
> - **All threads that are not daemon threads have died**, either by returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the run method.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I hav one more doubt regarding point 2. I read in the following link that since threads sharing address space, killing one thread can affect other thread also. Awaiting for your response

http://www.blurtit.com/q236205.html

Comment: A) The rant is completely wrong when saying "*Threads also simplify the structure of program*", and nothing it states afterwards can repair that miserable sentence. B) I don't think it applies to Java. C) Don't kill threads explicitly (by using Thread.stop). The Thread.stop method is deprecated for very good reasons.

Comment: The Thread helps a program to manage different tasks in the same time. The Thread.stop() method is deprecated because is unsafe (think about if the thread is managing some important data). Better to stop it with a boolean condition into a while loop in the run() method.

Comment: @aioobe - yes, the link reads very badly to me too.  Threads can simplify the structure of a program, (eg. by removing the need for the state-machines often required when handling events asynchronously on one thread), but it's cetainly not a general rule!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, in both cases. Threads run independantly of one another and there's no such thing as "parent" or "child" threads in this sense. The process will continue to run until there are no threads running in it.

A process is simply a container that contains some threads. The threads execute code. If there is one thread or more running inside a process container, the process will continue to exist. There's no symbiotic relationship between the threads, killing one will not kill another.